# Error: chdir() (errno 20)

Tags: php

I have this error when I'm trying to use chdir() in one of my pages:

> Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: Not a directory (errno 20) in
>   /home/****/public_html/index2.php on line 3

I have googled the error and found *nothing* concerning this error... What could be causing it? file permissions? And how can this be fixed?

Comment: When googling php errors make sure you do not enter the part after `in`, because that part is specific to your path and you may find nothing.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't google the path. I google the error, special words in it. And maybe "Not a directory (errno 20)" between quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `chdir(2)` man page:

```
   ENOTDIR
          A component of path is not a directory.
```

So, you're trying to change to something that is some other type of file.

Answer (score 3):

it usually means, that you try to access an object, which is not a directory. This may be checked via `is_dir(...)`.